# Filter an array in javascript with value 0

Tags: javascript

I got an array like this:

```
let arr = ['1','2','0','3','0',undefined,'0',undefined,'3','',''];
```

In order to filter the 'undefined' and '' element of this array and convert it to a number, I do like this:

```
arr = arr.filter(function(e){
    if(e){
        return parseInt(e);
    }
});
```

I got:

```
[1,2,3,3]
```

The 0 has also been filtered because 'return 0' means 'return false';

I want to know how do you normally do with this kind of problem?

### Update:

I saw the following answers propose many useful ways.
I learned a lot from it.

And if the element in the array need to be a number, not a string, should I traverse the array again? Or there is an alternative one-step method?

Comment: You mean "number" or "integer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could chain the wanted conditions.

```js
let array = ['1', '2', '0', '3', '0', undefined, '0', undefined, '3', '', ''];

array = array
    .filter(Boolean) // get only truthy values
    .map(Number);    // convert all values to number
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
return parseInt(e);
```

with

```
return !isNaN(e);
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = ['1','2','0','3','0',undefined,'0',undefined,'3','',''];
var output = arr.filter(function(e){
    if(e){
        return !isNaN(e);
    }
});
console.log( output );
```

**Edit**

For converting the values to **Number** as well, just add `.map( Number )` to the filter output

**Demo**

```js
var arr = ['1','2','0','3','0',undefined,'0',undefined,'3','',''];
var output = arr.filter(function(e){
    if(e){
        return !isNaN(e);
    }
}).map( Number );
console.log( output );
```

Comment: !isNaN(e); It can't filter the empty string.

Comment: @zhaozhiming It does, please check the demo as well.

Comment: `if(e){` filters empty strings, not `!isNaN`

Comment: @KoshVery I meant that my answer is filtering out empty strings, not `!isNaN` alone, which was already happening for OP.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding! and you forgot the conversion to numbers...

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks, the elements in the result array are strings, and I want them to be numbers, should I traverse the array again? Or is there an alternative one-step way?

Comment: Ohh, I had missed out on converting to Numbers, have fixed it now. Please check..

Comment: @gurvinder372 Oh yes, I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with array chain-functions:

```js
let arr = ['1', '2', '0', '3', '0', undefined, '0', undefined, '3', '', '']
  // filter valid elements (undefined and '' evaluates to false)
  .filter(e => e)
  // to exclude '0' from the list, do a bitwise-or
  //.filter(e => e|0)
  // cast into numbers
  .map(e => e * 1);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

With slight change

```js
let arr = ['1','2','0','3','0',undefined,'0',undefined,'3','',''];


arr = arr.filter(function(e){
    if( parseInt(e) >=0 ){
        return  e;
    }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thanks, the elements in the result array are strings, and I want them to be numbers, should I traverse the array again? Or is there an alternative one-step way?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ['1','2','0','3','0',undefined,'0',undefined,'3','',''];
let result = [];
for(let item of arr) {
  let num = +item;
  if(item === '' || Number.isNaN(num)) {
    continue;
  }
  result.push(num);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp.prototype.test()` with `RegExp` `/^\d+$/` to check if the value is one or more digits

```
arr = arr.filter(n => /^\d$/.test(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ['1','2','0','3','0',undefined,'0',undefined,'3','',''];

// map everything to Number (undefined becomes NaN)
// filter all valid numbers
arr = arr.map(Number).filter(e => !isNaN(e))
console.log(arr);
```